# React: Cannot design list item's index number (using map)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, text-alignment

I am trying to design a list, which consists a name, a highscore to the corresponding item, and the index before all. With easy 'className' designing, the highscore and name objects are successfully designable, but I cannot design the index. I would like to align the text to the left, and also set the width of it.

.js file:

```
 <div className="category">
    Expert
    <ol>
      {expert.map((data) => (
        <li className="item" key={data.id}>
          <div>
            <div className="name">{data.name}</div>
            <div className="score">{data.highscore}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  </div>
```

the result looks the following way currently:

[image]

What is the way to limit the shorten the width of the index number, and align the text of it to the left (if it reaches 10 or 100, it is very ugly)

The currently used .css classes have no influence on the index number, hence I don't post the code here, but it's kinda only the border coloring I did, and some width changing

Comment: You'd need to edit the CSS in the "name" class. Would be helpful for you to post that as well and probably the other 3 too. Alternatively, you can do an inline edit style{{ paddingRight: "-1rem" }} or marginLeft, style={{ width: "2rem" }} something like that.

Again you should post the css classes you're using.

Comment: The reason I didn't post those classes is that they don't work at all on the index number. Like if it wasn't even there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index columns width to be narrower you can use `padding-left: 0` on the  element.

Comment: Nope, there's no effect

Answer (score 0):

The marker for `<ol>` and `<ul>` elements cannot be styled (unless the `::marker` pseudo-element is updated and supported). You'll have to generate your own counter. For example:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: ol; // the value can be anything
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
li::before {
  content: counter(ol); // same case-sensitive name used above
  counter-increment: ol; // same case-sensitive name used above
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
}
```

You can adjust the `padding-left` and `left` properties to reduce/expand the width of the generated content.

Read more:

- [Using CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) (MDN)

Comment: This idea kind of works, the numbers appear, designable. But the numbers are overlapping each other. Not starting in the next line each time. I guess this is because of the 'map'. If it was manually created, just as in the link you gave it might work properly, but how can this line-breaking be done?

Comment: @Zolly The markers are positioned absolutely. You have to ensure you declare `position: relative;` on the parent (`li` or `.item`).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I would prefer first reset the at css the list styles as `ol { list-style:none; }` (you can't style them after all). Finally, at your component i would use the second param index to create a div or span with a proper className where I could manipulate it as:

```
 <div className="category">
    Expert
    <ol>
      {expert.map((data, index) => (
        <li className="item" key={data.id}>
          <div>
            <div className="list-id">{++index}</div>
            <div className="name">{data.name}</div>
            <div className="score">{data.highscore}</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ol>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `li:before` and this is the result.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ol {
  counter-reset: ol;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: center;
}
li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  content: counter(ol);
  counter-increment: ol;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
}
li div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <div class="name">
      Option 1
    </div>
    <div class="score">
      100
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="name">
      Option 2
    </div>
    <div class="score">
      100
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="name">
      Option 3
    </div>
    <div class="score">
      30
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```